# Outputting SQL statements in Console app

Tags: miniprofiler

We have our code instrumented so that in our MVC5 application, we can see the actual executed SQL.  We show the information using @MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes() on our _layout.cshtml file.  We configure miniprofiler as below

```
MiniProfiler.Settings.SqlFormatter = new InlineFormatter();
MiniProfiler.Start();
```

We want to use miniprofiler in our batch console applications to show the actual executed SQL.  We were looking at using Windows.Miniprofiler nuGet package, but it won't work with the current miniprofiler version of 3.2.0.157.
When we try to look at the results using below code, the SQL statements are not shown.

```
var friendlyString = MiniProfiler.Current.Render();
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?